# Initialize class more efficiently in Python

Tags: python, python-class

I have this code in which I initialize a class (Adapter) by the name I get from the request.
It seems to be a bit clumsy, and I'm sure there's a better/cleaner way of doing it.

```
from adapters.gofirst_adapter import GoFirstAdapter
from adapters.spicejet_adapter import SpiceJetAdapter
from adapters.airasia_adapter import AirAsiaAdapter

class Adapter():
    def __init__(self, adapter_name):
        if(adapter_name=='goFirst'):
            gofirst_adapter = GoFirstAdapter()
            self.adapter = gofirst_adapter
        if(adapter_name=='spiceJet'):
            spicejet_adapter = SpiceJetAdapter()
            self.adapter = spicejet_adapter
        if(adapter_name=='airAsia'):
            airasia_adapter = AirAsiaAdapter()
            self.adapter = airasia_adapter
```

What I'm aiming at is to have a list of the adapter names such as:

```
adapters = ['goFirst', 'spiceJet', 'airAsia']
```

and create the classes by the list.

Thank you.

Comment: Why use a list of strings? Why not just put the classes in a list. And the Adapter class seems pointless.

Comment: I'm getting the supported adapters list from a different part in the code.

Comment: Just pass the class itself, rather than its name, as the argument. `def __init__(self, adapter): self.adapter = adapter()`. (Or possibly letting the caller be responsible for creating and passing an instance instead of making `Adapter` create the instant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `dict` to map the parameter to the specific class:

```py
from adapters.gofirst_adapter import GoFirstAdapter
from adapters.spicejet_adapter import SpiceJetAdapter
from adapters.airasia_adapter import AirAsiaAdapter

class Adapter():
    adapters = {'goFirst':GoFirstAdapter, 'spiceJet':SpiceJetAdapter, 'airAsia':AirAsiaAdapter}
    def __init__(self, adapter_name):
        self.adapter = self.adapters[adapter_name]()
```

Comment: you'd want to also call the adapter, make a new instance instead of keeping a reference to the class :)

Answer (score 1):

something like this could work:

```py
from adapters.gofirst_adapter import GoFirstAdapter
from adapters.spicejet_adapter import SpiceJetAdapter
from adapters.airasia_adapter import AirAsiaAdapter

class Adapter():
    _adapter_builders = {
        "goFirst": GoFirstAdapter,
        "spiceJet": SpiceJetAdapter,
        "airAsia": AirAsiaAdapter,
    }

    def __init__(self, adapter_name):
        self.adapter = self._adapter_builders[adapter_name]()
```

Also it will raise an exception when the key is not available in the dictionary.